# Stop remote service using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've a script that stops remote services through [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation):

```
(get-service -ComputerName $server_ip -Name $service).Stop()
```

I want to force a service after five tries. I have build a counter, but what is the command to force a stop?

Comment: what do you mean by force, you can use the -Force param to stop service that have other services dependant on them.

Comment: a service wont stop and stays in StopPending i want to stop i using force, but i want to do that remotely using the get-service command

Answer (score 0):

If you have winRM enabled you can use the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock {
    Stop-Service $args[0] -Force } -ArgumentList $service
```

Comment: I tried it, but i wont work when the serves are not in a domain. In need the use WMI commands because that's the only way i have rights to start en stop the services.

Comment: It will work on all boxes which have WinRM set up, the ones which aren't on the domain need to be configured separately. This article might be helpful: http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/winrm-with-non-domain-joined-machine-using-certs/

Answer (score 0):

If by "force a stop" you mean you want to forcibly terminate (i.e. kill) the service process you could try killing the process via its PID:

```
$server  = '1.2.3.4'
$service = 'name'

Invoke-Command -Computer $server -ScriptBlock {
  param($svc)

  $Error.Clear()

  1..5 | % {
    Stop-Service -Name $svc
    if ($?) { break }  # exit from loop if previous command succeeded
  }

  if ($Error.Count -eq 5) {
    $pid = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$svc'").ProcessId
    (Get-Process -Id $pid).Kill()
  }
} -ArgumentList $service
```

Running the code via `Invoke-Command` is to avoid multiple remote connections.

This should work even for services that have the `NOT_STOPPABLE` flag set.